# Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, illegalstateexception

I have been trying to use eclipse RCP to create a standalone application and I get the below error whenever I try to run the application. I tried to look into previous solutions, but I feel I'm missing something (or may be I don't understand it good enough)

```
`!SESSION 2014-01-22 14:58:27.824 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.677
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.792
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255 [118]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.798
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.818
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.819
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.819
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.819
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.819
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.819
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.819
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.4.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.825
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.825
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255 [118] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.825
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.825
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.826
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.826
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.826
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.826
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.826
!MESSAGE Missing dynamically imported package org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.auth_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-01-22 14:58:28.831
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
`
```

My Config.ini file looks as follows

```
    #Product Runtime Configuration File
eclipse.application=ZilliRCP.application
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.product=ZilliRCP.product
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/ZilliRCP
osgi.bundles=ZilliRCP,\
  ch.qos.logback.classic,\
  ch.qos.logback.core,\
  com.ibm.icu,\
  javax.activation,\
  javax.annotation,\
  javax.inject,\
  javax.mail,\
  javax.servlet,\
  javax.xml,\
  org.eclipse.core.runtime,\
  org.apache.batik.css,\
  org.apache.batik.util,\
  org.apache.batik.util.gui,\
  org.apache.commons.lang,\
  org.apache.lucene.analysis,\
  org.apache.lucene.core,\
  org.dbe.businessModeller-vetis,\
  org.dbe.businessModeller-vetis-lib,\
  org.eclipse.ant.core,\
  org.eclipse.compare.core,\
  org.eclipse.core.commands,\
  org.eclipse.core.contenttype,\
  org.eclipse.core.databinding,\
  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable,\
  org.eclipse.core.databinding.property,\
  org.eclipse.core.expressions,\
  org.eclipse.core.filebuffers,\
  org.eclipse.core.filesystem,\
  org.eclipse.core.jobs,\
  org.eclipse.core.net,\
  org.eclipse.core.resources,\
  org.eclipse.core.runtime,\
  org.eclipse.core.variables,\
  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands,\
  org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,\
  org.eclipse.e4.core.di,\
  org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions,\
  org.eclipse.e4.core.services,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.di,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,\
  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3,\
  org.eclipse.emf,\
  org.eclipse.emf.common,\
  org.eclipse.emf.ecore,\
  org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,\
  org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.app,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.bidi,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.common,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.ds,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.event,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.preferences,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.registry,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.security,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.util,\
  org.eclipse.help,\
  org.eclipse.help.base,\
  org.eclipse.jetty.continuation,\
  org.eclipse.jetty.http,\
  org.eclipse.jetty.io,\
  org.eclipse.jetty.security,\
  org.eclipse.jetty.server,\
  org.eclipse.jetty.servlet,\
  org.eclipse.jetty.util,\
  org.eclipse.jface,\
  org.eclipse.jface.databinding,\
  org.eclipse.jface.text,\
  org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,\
  org.eclipse.osgi.services,\
  org.eclipse.swt,\
  org.eclipse.text,\
  org.eclipse.ui,\
  org.eclipse.ui.editors,\
  org.eclipse.ui.forms,\
  org.eclipse.ui.ide,\
  org.eclipse.ui.ide.application,\
  org.eclipse.ui.ide.application.source,\
  org.eclipse.ui.ide.source,\
  org.eclipse.ui.intro,\
  org.eclipse.ui.views,\
  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,\
  org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,\
  org.eclipse.xsd,\
  org.slf4j.api,\
  org.w3c.css.sac,\
  org.w3c.dom.smil,\
  org.w3c.dom.svg,\
  ch.qos.logback.slf4j,\
  javax.transaction,\
  org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86,\
  org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86,\
  org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86,\
  org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.hook,\
  org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook,\
  org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.hook,\
  org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86,\
  org.eclipse.ui.win32
osgi.splashPath = platform:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform  
<configurations> 
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" /> 
   </configurations> 
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.hook@4,org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
```

Comment: Are you generating this using a `xxx.product` file or some other way?

Comment: I am trying to generate it using the xxx.product.   I'm trying to model this plugin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sbeaver/files/) as an standalone application using RCP. Till not now much luck :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `.product` file enter the plugin dependencies on the `Dependencies` tab of the product editor. Use `Generate a default config.ini` file on the `Configuration` tab. This is much easier than trying to write the configuration files yourself.